# Sharepoint 2007 Alert emails going to wrong account

Tags: user-profile, email, alert

We've got a Sharepoint 2007 site, and alerts are in place for changes to Tasks & Milestones, so users receive emails whenever they are assigned a new Task.

However, many of those emails are going to the wrong account. The email will display the correct name, and everything appears as normal, it is just that the email address it is being sent to is incorrect.

When viewing the task itself in Tasks & Milestones, and clicking on the Assigned To link (which shows the correct user that should have received the alert) - which should display userDisp.aspx, this (almost always) results in a 404 error - FOR THOSE ALERTS THAT WERE SENT TO THE WRONG EMAIL ADDRESS.

Searching concentrating on this part yielded results based on the fact that My Site was initially enabled, but has been disabled in the last few months. This yielded the following advice:
In userDisp.aspx, replace any instances of 'Scope="Farm"' with 'Scope="Web"'.

This part I'm comfortable with, and I'd have thought it will fix the 404 issues (I can't yet perform the necessary iisreset to confirm it), but I wouldn't have thought that this will fix the issues with the alerts going to the incorrect address. I've tried searching for similar advice relating to alerts, but so far, I've found nothing.

As suggested by Dirbbel & Ziga (thanks both for your input) ... 
I've checked the email addresses associated with the accounts, they are correct. 
I've created a Console App and, for a sample of known errors, tried checking that the alert email address is the correct one for the associated user name, rather than the address that the message ends up with. This is the case - the alerts are associated with the correct email addresses, rather than the addresses where the emails are actually sent. As I say, I could not access the user accounts in userDisp.aspx, so I would have thought that the two issues are related?

Update: From speaking to users, it would appear that the users who SHOULD get the emails DO also get them. So, for example, here is the scenario:
- All users have an alert in place for when their individual Tasks & Milestones list is updated.
- When items from some other lists are created/updated, associated users will receive a new Task & Milestones item. Say, here, users A and B will get a new item, asking them to review an item which has been added to another list.
- Users A and B are sent an email each, as would be expected. However, user C is also sent both emails individually. These items do not appear in the Tasks & Milestones for user C, and the emails themselves show the Assigned To as user A and user B respectively.

Can anyone provide any advice? Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Ashley

Comment: Are you sure all the users have correct e-mail adresses in the users list?

Comment: Have you tried making a Console Application, running through all the alerts, displaying what user the alert belongs to and what email that user has, and compare that email to what you can see the user has in the UserProfile UI in Central Administration? (If not, try. And try running the App to check a specific user you know this error occurs at)

Comment: Check your AlertTemplates.xml file to see if it may have been modified to implement a custom alert action.
reference doc that describes the changes you would look for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx

Note that these changes can be done programmatically but most folks use this file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both for your input. I've created a Console App and, for a sample of known errors, tried checking that the alert email address is the correct one for the associated user name, rather than the address that the message ends up with. This is the case - the alerts are associated with the correct email addresses, rather than the addresses where the emails are actually sent.
As I say, I could not access the user accounts in userDisp.aspx, so I would have thought that the two issues are related?
Regards,
Ashley

Comment: Ashley, your question was migrated but I don't think your accounts are quite linked up. If you'd like, can you: (1) Register your account on http://stackoverflow.com. (2) Register your account on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com. (3) I'll merge your accounts and you'll be able to edit your question